# Как ограничить меру по нескольким измерениям (MDX)?

Tags: olap

В БД есть данные по сессиям пользователей. Для сессий есть дата начала и дата окончания.

Мне нужно построить куб и запрос по данному кубу, чтобы получать статистику по дням у скольких пользователей сессия завершилась в данный день. Причем посчитать нужно только тех, кто на 00:00:00 текущей даты имел открытую сессию, а на 00:00:00 следующего дня уже нет.

Аналогично нужно иметь возможность получать данные по неделям, месяцам, годам (Когда на начало соответствующего периода сессия открыта, а на конец периода закрыта).

Есть вот такой mdx-запрос:

```
SELECT
    { [Measures].[Count] } ON COLUMNS,
    { ( [Date Off].[Year].CHILDREN,[Date Off].[Month Name].CHILDREN,[Date Off].[Day Of Month].CHILDREN ) } ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube] 
WHERE ([Date Off].[Filter Value].&[20160818]:[Date Off].[Filter Value].&[20160918])
```

По нему я могу получить количество завершенных сессий по дням. Но проблема в том, что сессия может и начаться и завершиться в течение одного дня и тоже попадет в данную выборку. Как мне доработать запрос, чтобы учитывались только сессии, которые начались до текущего дня? И как еще ограничить так, чтобы не учитывать пользователей, у которых на конец дня оказалась открыта новая сессия?

Для этого в кубе есть измерения с датами начала сессий и датами начала следующей сессии, но как их тут применить, я не могу придумать

Answer (score 0):

В конструкции FROM можно указывать фильтры.
Вот кусок моего запроса:

```
FROM (SELECT ( STRTOSET("[Сети].[Наименование].&[4307]", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT (STRTOMEMBER("[Дата].[Г-М].[Месяц].&[201610]", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET("[Торговые точки].[Регион].&[39]", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS
FROM [Retail Analytics])
```